# PHP: convert UTC Date into seconds - not works with strtotime()

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I have this **UTC Date** `2017-07-16   12:00:07.8 UTC` (that calls `$dateconvert`) and I would like to convert it into seconds.
I tried to use `strtotime()` but it returns seconds in UTC removing another two hours and I don't understand why.

I'm in Italy and here Date is **UTC+2**, maybe `strtotime()` read `$dateconvert` with Italy time zone and when convert it into seconds removing that 2 hours?
Is it possible?

```
$anno_emsc= 2017;
$mese_emsc= 7;
$giorno_emsc= 16;
$ora_emsc= 12;
$minuto_emsc= 0;
$secondo_emsc= 7;


$dataconvert= strtotime($anno_emsc.'-'.$mese_emsc.'-'.$giorno_emsc.' '.$ora_emsc.':'.$minuto_emsc.':'.$secondo_emsc)+0;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1500199207 // strtotime removed 2 hours
```

Comment: If you have all the parts in separate variables, why not use [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) to convert them into a timestamp?

Comment: @rickdenhaan with gmmktime() works! if you write an answer i'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know all the parts, you can use [`gmmktime()`](http://php.net/gmmktime) to convert it into a timestamp. The "gm" version of `mktime()` knows that it's receiving a GMT/UTC date and will process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try and set your `date_default_timezone_set()` to your correct timezone and see if that fixes your issue. Sometimes your php instance will default to the wrong timezone.